# Efficient way to determine whether two IPath's point to the same resource

Tags: eclipse, path, equality

In Eclipse, what is the most efficient way to determine whether two `IPath`s point to the same resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deal with local files, the simpliest way is to use method **toFile()** of IPath interface and then check the equality of files. This worked for me, and seems to be efficient enough.

But if you also have to take into account UNC pathes (i.e. *//Server/Volume:/path*), this would be a bit more difficult and there are open questuions. Assume, two pathes *//Server/Volume:/path* and *//X.X.X.X/Volume/path* (where *X.X.X.X* is IP-address of the Server). Do you need to treat them as equal?

In any case, you should write your own comparison function, which compares the result of **segments()** method and then does anything you want with **getDevice()**.